# mysql, SQL Inner join internals

Tags: mysql, join

I have 4 tables with schemas as below :

```
create table A
(
    id int,
    B_id int, 
    D_id int
);


create table B
(
    id int,
    C_id int
);

create table C
(
    id int,
    C_Parent_id int
);

create table C_Parent
(
    id int 
);

create table D
(
    id int
);
```

In my case any row in A can be linked to a row in B / D and any row in B can be linked to a row in C & any row in C is **definitely** linked to a row in C_Parent.

I now insert some test data as below so that a row in table A is associated to a row in table B which is **NOT** associated to any row in table C.

I want to fetch some data from A , B(via A-> B link), D (A->D link) & C( if B->C link exists).

The problem is the query below does not work :

```
select A.id as Aid, B.id as bid, C.id as Cid, D.id as Did from
        A inner join B on A.B_id = B.id
    left outer join C on B.C_id = C.id
    inner join C_Parent on  C_Parent.id = C.C_Parent_id
    left outer join D on A.D_id = D.id;
```

Perhaps because the inner join is getting applied on the entire result of join obtained till this point & not just on the row from table C as is described in the join condition (**on  C_Parent.id = C.C_Parent_id**). Why is that?

I have modified above query to below query which works

```
select A.id as Aid, B.id as bid, C.id as Cid, D.id as Did from
        A inner join B on A.B_id = B.id
    left outer join 
    (
            C inner join C_Parent on  C_Parent.id = C.C_Parent_id
    )on B.C_id = C.id
    left outer join D on A.D_id = D.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: Why is that?

A: When `C.C_Parent_id` is NULL, the equality comparison in the join condition

```
 C_Parent.id = C.C_Parent_id
```

won't evaluate to TRUE, so a row is not returned, because it's an INNER JOIN operation.

And C.C_Parent_ID is going to be NULL anytime a row from B was returned when there wasn't a "matching" row from C.

---

Here's how I think about how the outer join operates. And this may help you understand what's happening.

For sake of example, consider

```
 SELECT b.id
      , c.b_id
   FROM b
   LEFT 
   JOIN c
     ON c.b_id = b
```

This is going to return all rows from b, along with matching rows from c, just like an inner join, except,

(as you already know) if this were an inner join, when there isn't a matching row from c, the row from b won't be returned.

But with the OUTER JOIN, the row from b *is* returned.

So this is how I think about it...

When there isn't a matching row from c, the database conjures a dummy row to serve in the place of a matching row from c. The dummy row has all the same columns as c, but all of the columns in the dummy row have a value of NULL. And since there is now a "matching" row, the row from b can be returned.

So it's like an inner join *except* the database is generating a "dummy" row of NULL values to serve as a matching row.

I'm not sure if that helps you understand it. But that's how I got my brain wrapped around an "outer join" operation.

---

So in your example, when a dummy row from C gets conjured to satisfy the outer join, all of the columns from C are NULL. Which is why, when you get to the join condition ... C.C_Parent_ID is NULL.

Comment: @nikel: Your last query works, I believe, because the added parens cause MySQL to perform the join operations in a different order. The inner join between C and C_Parent first, and then the result from that is outer joined to B. So the dummy rows of NULL that MySQL needs to conjure up are the rows "missing" from the the set (C join C_parent).

Comment: Yep..this makes complete sense now